# why is foundation-sites not compiling anymore on 6.3.x with brunch?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

when I try to use the latest foundation sites packages,
I get a bunch of new scss compile errors. 
If somebody has some clues, its highly appreciated.

steps to reproduce:

versions

```
elixir 1.4.0
phoenix 1.2.1
node 6.4.2
```

npm packages

```
"brunch": "~2.9.1",
"css-brunch": "~2.6.1",
"foundation-sites": "^6.3.0",
```

compile errors

```
08 Jan 23:48:36 - info: compiling
08 Jan 23:48:37 - error: Compiling of web/static/scss/application.scss failed. Error: It's not clear which file to import for '@import "../_vendor/normalize-scss/sass/normalize"'.
       Candidates:
         ../_vendor/normalize-scss/sass/normalize
         ../_vendor/normalize-scss/sass/_normalize.scss
       Please delete or rename all but one of these files.
        on line 9 of node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss
>> @import "../_vendor/normalize-scss/sass/normalize";
   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

with this setting, i could fix the issue :)
hopefully it will safe some others hours of searching.
kudos to this guy: https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-setup-foundation-sites-6-brunch-phoenix-app/2704/3

the brunch-config needs some adjustment, because, foundation leads to some strange behavior with native lib-sass. I figured out, that with the ruby compiler, there was no path problem.

So, when you include it explicitly from package.json and in the brunch-config, a normaliz-scss can be found and imported, even though it fails from foundation.

```
  plugins: {
    babel: {
      presets: ['es2015', 'es2016', 'react'],
      // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
      ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/],
    },
    sass: {
      mode: 'native',
      precision: 8,
      options: {
        includePaths: [
          'node_modules/normalize-scss/sass',
          'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss',
          'node_modules/motion-ui/src',
        ],
      },
    },
    postcss: {
      processors: [
        require('autoprefixer')(['last 8 versions']),
        require('csswring')()
      ]
    },
  },
```